# Start WP Pagination From Number 1 in URL

Tags: posts, loop, pagination

I am using this code to paginate gallery post type images:

```
$images = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'post__in' => $image_ids,
'orderby' => 'post__in',
'posts_per_page' => 1
));
```

then display them in the loop, it puts page links on the page like: 1.......15
Each link button has its corresponding link truly like this:

domain.com/post1/

domain.com/post1/2

domain.com/post1/3

domain.com/post1/4

And what I need is to make the first one get the "1" in front of the link like:

domain.com/post1/1

So how do I do it?